# DatePicker not available in XAML in Windows Phone 8.1 project retargeted from 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1

I've recently updated a Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Phone 8.1. I'm trying to add a `<DatePicker />` control (newly available in Windows Phone 8.1) to the XAML but it's not available in my XAML.

I get the errors:

> The name "DatePicker" does not exist in the namespace
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

and

> The type 'DatePicker' was not found. Verify that you are not missing
>   an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been
>   built.

and

> The tag 'DatePicker' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

However, if I create a new Windows Phone app the `DatePicker` is available there.

Also, I can create and add the DatePicker via the codebehind, just not in XAML.

I have checked and can confirm the project is targeting Windows Phone 8.1, and as far as I can see I am referencing the correct assembly:

[image]

What do I need to do to make the DatePicker available in XAML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You upgraded your project to a windows phone silverlight 8.1 app, not a windows phone windows runtime 8.1. The new DatePicker is only available for windows phone windows runtime 8.1. In a windows phone silverlight 8.1 app you will still need to use the DatePicker from the windows phone toolkit.

Comment: I can see the lack of this support in my VS 2013 when trying to create a new WP81 Silverlight App - but I have not found any clear MS documentation on this. And MS seems to suggest - in some channels at least - that it should work. Confusing.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e384df08-6226-45b2-9114-3c8b67693676/wp-81-datepicker-bug?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# for that matter.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
```

`DatePicker` is available within this namespace as mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.aspx).
Also make sure your XAML has following namespaces:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YourAppName"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
    x:Class="YourAppName.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

These are the basic namespaces required to format a WP8.1 app's XAML page.
Try these if still not working:

- Use `Toolbox` and drag and drop the `DatePicker` from the list. It will automatically add the missing namespaces.
- After each edit, make sure you `Rebuild` the solution to reload the designer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try working out with the sample code from [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-DatePicker-and-94ef5709).

Please refer to the below sample for Windows Phone 7, hope this would work for WP 8.1.

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Hope it helps!